# Improper record selection

Tags: crystal-reports, subreport

My main report gathers information from three columns of a table. One column is a date, another is a "string" Action, and the other is a "string" Message. The Message column contains a long string delimited by a commas. I gather required information from that string by splitting it by the comma. This required information is then used as parameters for my sub report, which I have in the detail section. In addition to the details section, I have three page headers. The first header contains my title and the other two are headings that I toggle suppression based on whether an error exist or not. I am pulling only the records that date matches the the current date and the Action string is in ("Error Counts", "Reporting Errors", "Successful Run"). When the transfer is successful, a record is inserted in the table mentioned above with an action equal to "Successful Run" and message that contains totals that I want displayed in one of the headers. The "successful run" header has the following formula for suppression:

```
{ELB_PIMSTRANSFERLOG.ACTION} in ["Error Counts", "Reporting error"]
```

When there is an error in the transfer, there is a record inserted with an action equal to "Error Counts" and the message contains totals that I want displayed in the other header. The "error counts" header has the following formula for suppression:

```
{ELB_PIMSTRANSFERLOG.ACTION} = 'Successful Run'
```

The details section has the same suppression formula. Basically, when there are no error you will see the successful header with a report summary. When there is an error(s) you will see the error header with a report summary. Also in the details section you will see information on each error through the sub report. My problem is that when there is an error, I need the error heading to appear with it totals. The totals are in the message column of the "Error Counts" action entry, which is only one entry. But the errors have an "Reporting Errors" action. So if I have fifteen errors, I will see each error detail information in the details section like expected but the totals will show up in at the end on a new page. Here is one of my equations for one of the error totals:

```
if {ELB_PIMSTRANSFERLOG.ACTION} = 'Error Counts' then
Split ({ELB_PIMSTRANSFERLOG.MESSAGE},",")[4]
```

I need to find out how to grab the totals from that one "Error Counts" entry and have it appear in the heading section. When there is success there is only one entry that will meet criteria, so everything comes up correctly. But when there is an error, you have all the error entries and you have the one entry for the error counts as part of the group of records. This is my dilemma that I don't think I can fix so I have to figure out something. Is there a way around this?

Comment: by your question I understood that you need individual error total instead of sum of all errors at the end and also that sum should display in header, currently it is getting displayed in footer. Is it correct?

Comment: Next time try to show how design looks which will be easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late post. Thank you for your reply Siva, but I figured it out. Well I would say I found a solution. 
[image: report screen shot]

Instead of using Page Headers, I used Group Headers and grouped by my "string" Action. Then I changed the logic in my suppression formulas for each section. Instead of suppressing each of the three sections shown above in the image, I didn't suppress the first group header (Successful Run Counts), I suppressed the second group header (Error Count) whenever the Action was in ["Successful Run", "Reporting error"], and I suppressed the third group header (Individual error detail) whenever the Action was ["Successful Run", "Error Counts"]. That worked for me.